# Choose which popups should be allowed from webview in electron app

Tags: electron

I'm not using **allowpopups** property to allow opening popups from webview in electron app, instead i'm handling 'new-window' on per case basis.

Here is my event handler

```
content.addEventListener('new-window', function (e) {
  var url = e.url;
  var hostname = (new URL(url)).hostname.toLowerCase();

  if (hostname.indexOf('dropbox.com') !== -1 && url.indexOf('chooser') !== -1) {
    // this should open window but it doesnt
    return true;

  } else {
    content.loadURL(url);
    e.preventDefault();
  }  
});
```

As you can see if event that triggered this handler has url of dropbox (for example) i want electron to allow opening that window as intended.

If that is not the case, i should open that url in the electron app.

... but this doesn't work, when dropbox url is used, i get nothing. Any advices on what i'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thanks to Tim i managed to find a solution for this problem.

If we try to prevent opening new windows or allow them to open, 'new-window' can't be of use for us if we're trying to handle it in renderer process. If we try to handle that event in renderer process, popup/window will open no matter what we do in that even handler.

Solution is to handle that event in main process, but before that, we need to add `allowpopups` and `webpreferences="nativeWindowOpen=true"` to our webview.

`allowpopups` obviously allows popups in the first place, and `webpreferences="nativeWindowOpen=true"` uses native Chromium window.open, with added benefit that window opening and `new-window` event are happening in sequence, not asynchronously.

Code for webview should look something like this:

```
<webview src="page.html" webpreferences="nativeWindowOpen=true" allowpopups></webview>
```

After that in main process (usually `main.js`) we can handle what we want to allow to open in electron popup and what not. First we have to get right handle on webview and then we can handle the `new-window` event:

```
app.on('web-contents-created', function (webContentsCreatedEvent, contents) {
  if (contents.getType() === 'webview') {
    contents.on('new-window', function (newWindowEvent, url) {
      console.log('block');
      newWindowEvent.preventDefault();
    });
  }
});
```

I managed to scramble this solution with help of Tim and by reading the comments on pull request here https://github.com/electron/electron/pull/9568#issuecomment-306339926

Hope this will be helpful to someone.

Comment: can you answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69206387/target-blank-based-link-in-webview-in-electron-js-are-not-opening-when-nativewi

Answer (score 1):

You should be hooking the [`new-window`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/web-contents#event-new-window) event on your `BrowserWindow` `webContents`:

```
myBrowserWindow.webContents.on('new-window', (event, url) => {
  var hostname = (new URL(url)).hostname.toLowerCase();

  if (hostname.indexOf('dropbox.com') !== -1 && url.indexOf('chooser') !== -1) {
    // this should allow open window
  } else {

    event.preventDefault();
  } 
})
```

Comment: Hello Tim. Thanks for help, however **content** in my code is reference to webview and it supports 'new-window' event. Client application i'm writing is loaded inside of that webview, and therefore my code get's executed. However, if i use code like you provided and log something to the console it get's logged but window still doesn't open.

Comment: Ah, that was not clear from your question! Are you tagging your web-view with the [allowpopups](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/webview-tag#allowpopups) attribute? Its required if you want the webview to be able to open windows. https://github.com/electron/electron/pull/2868

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, my bad. If i add **allowpopups**, then i can't selectively open popups, popup is always opened. To be clear what i want to accomplish is to allow google drive & dropbox to open popup, and all other external links should be open in browser.

Comment: So you can't use `allowpopups` with the `new-window` event? Is that documented anywhere? My understanding was that without `allowpopups`, `window.open` would not work at all. The docs say `"If "on", the guest page will be allowed to open new windows."` so I would assume that if its off, the guest page will not be allowed to open new windows...

Comment: When allow popups is off, new-window event is triggered, and i can do whatever i want with that event (other than allowing it to open popup if i allow it with my contition inside new-window event). My guess is that's because opening/block of the window and new-window happens asynchronously not sequentially.Basically if i add allowpopups to webview and define new-window event handler no matter what i do in new-window event handler popup opens. even if i add alert() in that handler, to halt execution of that handler at first line of it, the popup will still open even if i did not dismiss alert.

Comment: That makes me think that new-window does not happen before opening/blocking window and therefore i cannot selectively allow new window opening/blocking. I might be wrong, i'm not sure though.

Comment: Have you tried the `nativeWindowOpen=yes` option detailed here: https://electronjs.org/docs/api/window-open

Comment: I stumbled upon a thread that resembles my problem, nativeWindowOpen is in play and webview is also in play. It looks like that new-window handler on webview in renderer processes cannot block opening popups and that needs to be defined in main process https://github.com/electron/electron/pull/9568#issuecomment-306339926 I'll try to implement something here and if i can do it, i'll get back here with solution

Comment: Tim, thanks. I finally found the solution and it works as expected, i'll add the answer for future readers

Comment: can you answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69206387/target-blank-based-link-in-webview-in-electron-js-are-not-opening-when-nativewi