# Image and Video links do not open in Electron app

Tags: image, video, webview, electron, tags

Hi,
I face a very weird thing from electron that I could not understand why.
Suppose we develop a very simple webView tag based electron app like following link

[simple electron webview sample](https://github.com/cba85/electron-webview)

Then I changed the default website to [www.varzesh3.com](http://www.varzesh3.com) which has some video links always.
Then when I click on the image or video links, those links does not open and I do not know why.
It seems that because those links are not normal links, they wont open.

Please let me know if you have any ideas in this regard.

Thanks

Comment: Are you saying you are stuck on the front page, because links do not open other pages? Does the above code work okay with any other sites? Like when an image is clicked, do their own links actually go to the requested/linked page?

Comment: href links are working properly, but links that exists on <a> tags are not working.
For example:

<a class="title" target="_blank" href="https://video.varzesh3.com/video/255720/ding">
    <h4>ding</h4>
</a>
I think there is a problem with links that are inside other tags which are not direct href tags.

Comment: Do you really need anchor tags? Why not change that to Div and put clickable text that opens the link?

Comment: I would like to use this program to open other websites.
www.Varzesh3.com website has a video carousel section that gives some videos to view.
I can not open those videos in electron app. 
in that carousel section 3 or 4 or more videos exist.
Please have a look at that website and try to open it with following github project:

https://github.com/cba85/electron-webview

Then you well see that those video links do not open.

Comment: The point is that I do not develop the web contents by myself and I would like to use webview tag to open other websites. some other websites has anchor tabs and I have to support them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find a link and based on it, I can remove this bug.

[Choose which popups should be allowed from webview in electron app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48298364/choose-which-popups-should-be-allowed-from-webview-in-electron-app)

This is the updated fork of electron-webview project that in which I resolve that bug.
https://github.com/monhi/electron-webview